# Take data from one json and put it in another

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very large json file, and inside of that json file is an array. I would like to use JavaScript to take that json as an argument, parse through the json and only take certain elements from it and put it into a new json file, below is an example of what I mean:

```
{
"contextType": "Account",
"preferences": null,
"custodianCode": null,
"data": [{
"id": "0",
"account": "11111111",
"field2": true,
"field3": false,
"field4": "BROK",
"field5": "Broker",
"field6": "1",
"field7": "Cash"
 },{
 "id": "1",
"account": "222222222",
"field2": true,
"field3": false,
"field4": "BROK",
"field5": "Broker",
"field6": "1",
"field7": "Cash"
}]

}
```

And I want to pull from that and get something like this as a new json

```
{
 "newArray": [{
"id": "0",
"account": "11111111",
"field2": true,
"field3": false,
"field4": "BROK",
"field6": "1"
 },{
"id": "0",
"account": "222222222",
"field2": true,
"field3": false,
"field4": "BROK",
"field6": "1"
}]

}
```

Also the file is local to my computer and can be outputted locally as well, I am trying to use node.js and JavaScript this is what I have so far

```
 var json = require('./simple.json');
 var keeperFields = ["id", "account", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field6"];
 var newJSON = {newArray: [] };
 var i;
 var fields;

 for (i = 0; i < keeperFields.length; i++) {
   for (fields in json) {
     if (json.hasOwnProperty(keeperFields[i])) {
       newJSON.newArray.push(keeperFields[i]);
       }
      }
     }

   console.log(newJSON);
```

This is just a small example the real json file is huge with thousands of lines. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

This current solution is giving me a console log of { newArray: []} instead of the expected result above

Comment: You need to parse the JSON into an object you can read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You needed to start with the .data field of json

```js
json = {
 "contextType": "Account",
 "preferences": null,
 "custodianCode": null,
 "data": [{
  "id": "0",
  "account": "11111111",
  "field2": true,
  "field3": false,
  "field4": "BROK",
  "field5": "Broker",
  "field6": "1",
  "field7": "Cash"
 },{
  "id": "1",
  "account": "222222222",
  "field2": true,
  "field3": false,
  "field4": "BROK",
  "field5": "Broker",
  "field6": "1",
  "field7": "Cash"
 }]
}

var keeperFields = ["id", "account", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field6"];
var newJSON = {newArray: [] };
json.data.forEach(function(obj) {
 var newObj = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < keeperFields.length; i++) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keeperFields[i])) {
   newObj[keeperFields[i]] = obj[keeperFields[i]];
  }
 }
 newJSON.newArray.push(newObj);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(newJSON));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this lose the field names on the new array? Never mind I see it now.

Comment: When I run this in node I get the output you sought - just learn how code snippets work so you can see it in action! But I agree that iterating over keeper fields in the way you do makes more sense

Comment: thanks that worked great, I should really start using foreach more too

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the input file is standardized you can do this more easily. Something like this should work...

```js
// assuming you loaded your data into a json object named json and that it contains a field called "data" that contains a list of the records you want to inject into the new array.
var json = require('./simple.json');
var keeperFields = ["id", "account", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field6"];
var newJSON = {
  newArray: []
};

// put the list of records into a convenience var.
var records = json.data;
// loop through the records
for (var recordId in data) {
  // Grab the current record
  var record = records[recordId];
  // Create a new record
  var newRecord = [];
  // Loop through the keeperfields. Since they are named you can create fields in the new record using the same field names
  for (var field in keeperFields) {
    // Copy record data from source record to new record 
    newRecord[field] = record[field];
  }
  // append the new record to the new data set
  newJSON.newArray.push(newRecord);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is a thorough explanation its nice to see the different ways to do the same thing